# Ansible variable arithmetic operation

Tags: ansible

I would like to retrieve the modulo of two Ansible variables.

How can we do something like that?

```
kernel_shmallV: "{{ sys_mem.stdout }} % {{sys_page_size.stdout }}"
```

Answer (score 2):

Ansible uses Jinja2 templating language. You write Jinja2 expressions inside `{{ }}`. Anything inside the quotes, but outside the braces is a string.

What you wrote in the question are two independent expressions each printing the value of a variable separated by a string `%`.

What you are looking for is:

```
kernel_shmallV: "{{ sys_mem.stdout|int % sys_page_size.stdout|int}}"
```

---

<sup>Stdout values returned by `command` or `shell` modules are of string type, hence casting to integer with `int`.</sup>